# How can I subdivide this object so my particles emit more evenly from faces?

Tags: modeling, particles, subdivision-surface

I'm trying to emit particles from this face, with the particles spread evenly/randomly across it... however, because the faces are spread across it horizontally, the particles are not covering it how I would like.  They're mostly clumping up where there are higher concentrations of vertices.

I'm guessing the solution would be to subdivide it in a way that there are more vertical cuts, resulting in more square faces, or more vertices spread evenly throughout the surface.

But when I try and simply subdivide I only end up with more horizontal faces.  And the knife tool is way too tedious to achieve the level of detail I need.

How can I pull this off?

[Project file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mdenpgmautq3129/Subdivide%20Cubically%20How.blend?dl=0)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't imagine you need to edit your mesh for this. Just ticking the *Even Distribution* option of your Particle System under the *Emission > Source* panel should do. The old particle system is pretty finicky so you might need to enable and disable it a few times, undo/redo, or reset the timeline to see it, but it does work:

[image]

At the end there, I'm selecting everything, then <kbd>X</kbd> (Delete menu) > *Limited Dissolve* to get rid of most edges without affecting the outline. That can also be a help in situations like these if you don't want to bother with remeshing.

Comment: Oh man I'm glad you mentioned forcing the particle system to update because I was banging my head against the wall wondering why Even Distribution wasn't working.  Per your answer I just cycled the number of particles and viola! everything magically jumped into place.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

To start, I disabled the particles from preview so you can see the mesh better. Use a *Decimate Modifier* set to *Planar* to remove all the "junky" topology. Apply the modifier:

[image: Dec1]

Then select the whole mesh and extrude (E) it "upwards" on the Z-Axis. This is necessary for the next step to work:

[image: Dec2]

Add a Remesh Modifier set to "Sharp" with octree depth of 8 or so.

[image: Dec3]

Select one face on the "top" of the mesh then pick *Select > Select Similar > Normal* from the menu at top:

[image: Dec4]

Then pick *Select > Invert* from the top to select all the faces *not* on the "top" of the mesh.

[image: Dec5]

Delete those faces:

[image: Dec6]

Move the mesh back "down" on the Z-Axis (if necessary):

[image: Dec7]

Unhide the particles:

[image: Dec8]

Comment: I just noticed, however, that the particles go a bit wonky after this.  You will probably need to re-do your particle system (delete and re-add the modifier ) , and possibly apply rotation and scale to your object as well.

Comment: Hey man thank you for this. @Kuboa's solution actually solved my problem without needing to do this, but I'm super glad I asked and grateful for this explanation. This is literally a technique I knew nothing about, and it will come in handy a lot in the future (and in the past had I only known!).  Cheers

Comment: @GlenCandle Yeah - I thought you wanted  the mesh subdivided in addition to the particles "just working" - at least you can use the example if/when you need to clean up dirty topology in the future (I'm guessing that mesh came from an SVG - they always need cleaning).

Comment: Ha, yeah, SVG.  I had to clean up the control points, but I never knew a good way to clean up all the faces after converting to mesh.  And I always wondered what the Remesh Modifier was good for. Now I know! Thanks again.